# Using Swift 3 Measurement and Unit classes in Realm

Tags: realm, swift3

Does Realm support the new Measurement and Unit classes in Swift 3 Foundation? It doesn't appear to be the case currently. If not, is there a recommended strategy for a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Realm to remain consistent across platforms, it cannot expose support for types that cannot be represented on other platforms. So don't expect native Realm support for Measurement and Unit types recently added in Foundation.

However, it's easy to use a computed property for that:

```
class MyModel: Object {
    private dynamic var _angleInDegrees: Double = 0
    var angle: Measurement<UnitAngle> {
        get {
            return Measurement(value: _angleInDegrees, unit: UnitAngle.degrees)
        }
        set {
            _angleInDegrees = newValue.value
        }
    }

    override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
        return ["angle"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the sample code. The problem I'm having is enabling the user to dynamically change the Unit type used for a given Measurement do I can't hard code it. I guess I could use en enum or some other data structure as a key and use a dynamic property in a similar way to your example (unless there are any other suggestions of course!)